# Embed/REST API for azure analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, azure, model-view-controller

Is there an API available to pull telemetry/insights data for websites from the azure portal, so I can display that data on my 3rd party site? I'm looking for something similar to Google Analytics embed API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a specific API for Azure Web Apps analytics (the new name, as I found out today). However, you can configure your web site to log to Azure storage - either table storage or blob storage, and then use the regular storage REST APIs (or use the storage client classes from one of the Azure SDKs). You can do this configuration when you enable logging in the Azure portal. The choices for log destination are File (i.e. the local filesystem - these can then be pulled by FTP) or Table or Blob (these can then be accessed by the storage REST API).

It is summarised here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Note: In that link they describe how you can stream logs for real time log viewing (using PowerShell or the Azure command line tools). I think this is intended for debugging purposes rather than embedding in an application, but it might help you...

An alternative approach (disclaimer: I never tried this) is to integrate NewRelic into your application and then use their REST API to extract their monitoring information:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apis/requirements/extracting-metric-data

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid having to manually parse the log files, but I guess that's the only way for now.